# Replacing characters in a non well-formed XML body

Tags: java, xml, non-well-formed

In a (Java) code that I'm working on, I sometimes deal with a non well-formed XML (represented as a Java `String`), such as:

```
<root>
  <foo>
    bar & baz < quux
  </foo>
</root>
```

Since this XML will eventually need to be unmarshalled (using JAXB), obviously this XML as is will throw exception upon unmarshalling.

What's the best way to replace the `&` and the `<` to its character entities? For `&`, it's as easy as:

```
xml.replaceAll("&", "&amp;")
```

However, for the `<` symbol, it's a bit tricky since obviously I don't want to replace the `<` that's used for the XML tag opening 'bracket'.

Other than scanning the string and manually replacing `<` in the XML body with `&lt;`, what other option can you suggest?

Comment: How would your program distinguish a </foo> in the text, within the foo element, from a </foo> in the XML, ending the foo element?

Comment: How can you tell whether a `<` is a tag opening?

Comment: Is each tag and value printed on a single line as in your example?

Comment: @Sjoerd: for the purpose of this app, it's safe to assume that there will be no 'XML closing tag' in the body, ie, there will be no `</foo>` in the body

Comment: @stacker: no, the whole XML can be in 1 line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, the best way to repair malformed XML is to send it back to whoever produced it and ask them to send you well-formed XML instead. You show a trivial example, which potentially could have a solution, but a general method for repairing malformed XML is going to be a horrendous job.

And since XML parsers aren't required to handle malformed XML, your parser isn't required to either. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need more advance logic. Best to first locate all real tags using a regular expression like "(<[^>]+>)" and only replace text outside those matches, but obviously you won't be able to use a replaceAll method then. It will be more of a plumbing job...

Answer (score 1):

Though its an old post but i thought it might help somebody else..I had the same requirement/issue and i could resolve using the following code.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class XMLTest {

/**
* @param args
*/

public static void main(String[] args) {

String xml = "<xml><body>" +
"<message>something < between <<<  somthing </message>" +
"<text> testing  >> > testing </text>" +
"</body></xml>";

Pattern replaceGTPattern = Pattern.compile(">[^<](.[^<]*)(>)+");

Matcher m = replaceGTPattern.matcher(xml);

String replacement;
StringBuffer intermXml = new StringBuffer();


while(m.find()){

    replacement = ">"+m.group(0).substring(1).replaceAll(">", ";&gt");


    m.appendReplacement(intermXml,replacement);


    }


    m.appendTail(intermXml);

Pattern replaceLTPattern = Pattern.compile("<(.[^>]*)(<)+");

m = replaceLTPattern.matcher(intermXml);

StringBuffer finalXml = new StringBuffer();

while(m.find()){

    replacement = m.group(0).substring(0,m.group(0).length()-1).replaceAll("<", ";&lt").concat("<");


    m.appendReplacement(finalXml,replacement);


    }

    m.appendTail(finalXml);

    System.out.println(finalXml);

}
}
```